# How to adjust height of ListViewItem as *?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView and am adding 5 ListViewItem. in that the 3rd item's height should take the rest of the height like row definition given in the code.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Any Idea on this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a good idea to use ListView while all you want to do is place 5 items in there?

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix: its not about the number of items, am just said for example. i need a item's height to be * and why ListView isn't a good idea?

Comment: I think the only way would be to do it manually, by hooking up to the ListView's LayoutUpdated event and updating the heights one by one.

Comment: then you didn't really explained what are you trying to achieve. What's so special about 3rd item? It's not clear from your question. You said you want to add 5 items and 3rd should have height *. Now you have said it was just an example... why didn't you explain that in your question? Nobody can help you untill you explain properly what are you trying to do.

Comment: You are looking for an accordion control.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this works..

> yourListView.GetItemRect(itemIndex).Height=foo;

Can you try using any logic, to set the value for foo?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you are using *, it is to mean that the control on this will take the free spaces left. Indirectly speaking the size of your List view and the whole grid size matters. So keeping * is not a problem. But if you want to set with the controls' size use `auto`.

Still you can use other containers like stackpanel to manage the list view control size by adding the stackpanel to the third row.